# PowerPoint VBA - Code works in debug mode but fails to run in compile mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Hello This code woks on debug mode but fails to run in complie mode at `CommandBars.ExecuteMso`
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPasteAsUnion()

     Dim sld As Slide
     Dim shp As Shape

     Dim ShapeOne As String
     Dim ShapeTwo As String
     Dim oshpR As ShapeRange


     For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
     ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide sld.SlideIndex
          For Each shp In sld.Shapes
           If shp.HasTextFrame = True Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText = True Then
                      ShapeOne = shp.Name
                      ShapeTwo = shp.Name & "_1"
                      With shp.Duplicate
                         .Left = shp.Left
                         .Top = shp.Top
                         .Name = ShapeTwo
                      End With
                            Set oshpR = sld.Shapes.Range(Array(ShapeOne, ShapeTwo))
                            oshpR.Select
                            CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapesUnion")
                    End If
                End If
         Next
     Next
End Sub
```

PowerPoint Version I'm using : PowerPoint 2016 (System : Windows 7).

Error While compiling:

> Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'ExecuteMso' of objects
>   '_CommandBars' Failed

Comment: Edit your question with the error you are getting

Comment: Your code compiles w/o error here (PPT 2010 and PPT 2016, both under Windows.)  Are you using a Mac version of PPT, by any chance?  I don't think that CommandBars.ExecuteMso is supported there.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Are you tested with the text frame on multiple slides.? because  i'm getting error here on PowerPoint 2016  on windows 7 system.
Can you please help.? Thanks.

Comment: @ShanayL Edited.
Can you please take a look. Thanks.!

Comment: @Lalitk The problem seems to be that you can't perform a union on shapes that include text. Try adding the ShapesUnion command to the ribbon or QAT.  Then draw and select a couple of rectangles; the Union button is enabled.  Add text to one or both of the rectangles and the Union button is disabled.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg with all due respect the code works in debug mode (Step by step) it means it working with the text frame. The only thing is that it shows error while compile.
Please kindly download the example PPT : [Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1p8fqiU-amXVTZTc043QmNER0k)
Thank you!

Comment: Your link requires signing into a google account.  For various reasons, that's not practical. Both Dropbox and OneDrive allow creating links that point to a file w/o requiring log-in.  Does google docs not allow this?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I'm sorry I really don't know what problem is causing. Well what about wetransfer [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a68b190898163fcbef8a6044f99c177420170912200911/9a1623)
Thank you.

Comment: @Lalitk That link worked; thanks!  I'll have a look a bit later. I have a few deadlines to meet right now.

Comment: @Lalitk This isn't going to make you smile:  I downloaded your file, copied your code to another file and ran it against your file.  It worked.  No complaints, no compile errors.  But at least now I see why I was misled about shapes with text in them ... they don't work in PPT 2010, but do in 2016.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks for comment. I got to figured it out my code and end up with solution that, It is  failing due to a timing issue so by adding DoEvents before the ExecuteMso line the code works. It is depend on machine speed. Well Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Lalitk Glad you got it sorted; I saw your post about the problem on another forum and figured you were on the way to an answer.  Congrats!